# Assembly programming - "variables" defined using (what looks like) labels, or variable names?

Tags: assembly, nasm, intel-syntax

I have seen "variables" in assembly "defined" using two syntaxes, the first looks like a label, and the second looks like a variable name. Can the two be used interchangeably, or is there a specific reason for each ones use?

For example:

```
msg db "Hello World",0x0a
```

looks kind of like a variable name in C / C++, whereas

```
msg: db "Hello World",0x0a
```

looks kind of like a label in either asm or C / C++.

1. Is there a reason for using one or the other syntax?
2. What is the difference between them?
3. If I `msg: db "Text",0x0a`, can I then `mov rax, [msg]` or do I need to `mov rax, [msg:]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [NASM documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html): `The colon after a label is also optional.` I guess this means that both pieces of code create a label called `msg`.

1. Code style, readability & consistency come to mind as a reason for using one over the other. But seeing as the semantics are the same, I would imagine that's the only reason.
2. Given `x: db 0` and `x db 0`, it would seem that both create a label called `x`.
3. I would say you would do `mov rax, [msg]`. This is because in NASM, when you create a label, the semicolon at the end is not included in the name but rather is a hint to the assembler that the end of the label's name has been reached.